# What was the significance of the chess piece?

Tags: analysis, the-count-of-monte-cristo

In 2002 movie *The Count of Monte Cristo*, there was a game played involving a chess king that was passed back and forth every time one of the characters had a major victory.  Then, they would say "Kings to you" or "Kings to me."  I started to play this game with my friends, but I think we played it wrong (I'll explain in the comments to maintain accuracy in the question.)  How did this game work and what was the deeper meaning?

Comment: We would say "kings to me" when we won.

Comment: You're referring to the Jim Caveziel/Guy Pearce version, I assume?

Comment: Hmmm...I don't remember it in the book and I am not as familiar with any film versions as much as I am the 2002 version with Jim Caveziel and Guy Pearce.  I really don't know if that's in any other version or not.

Comment: Also, I don't believe that they were playing an actual game called "kings to you"  that was just the piece of the chess board that they would use as a symbol when one of them bested one another in a friendly way...until it turned out not-so-friendly.

Comment: Correct.  I don't think that it was an actual game.

Comment: You might want to also maybe change your question title to "What was the significance of the chess piece" or something along those lines.  you don't need the movie title in the question title...just fyi :)

Comment: In the TV show Bones, Dr. Hodgins and the squinterns frequently declare themselves "King of the Lab" whenever they make an important finding or solve a particularly problematic evidentiary (?) dilemma. I'm also voting that this "king's to you/me" thing is something similar and just happens to involve an actual chess piece.

Answer (score 8):

In [this](http://tank2wessells.weebly.com/1/post/2013/01/the-chess-piece-in-the-count-of-monte-cristo.html) blog has a good analysis:

> the chess piece in "The Count of Monte Cristo" was a powerful symbol. At first it was set up as a mutual keepsake that represented the friendship between Fernand and Edmund. Then after the betrayal of Fernand, he gives the piece back to Edmund to "remember better days." At the end of the movie, after Fernand's life has been taken away to sate Edmund's lust for revenge, Fernand looks into chests he expects to be filled with gold and instead finds only the chess piece. This is very powerful, not only has Edmund revealed his identity this way, he has also renounced their friendship. In addition, by putting it in the chests that were filled with the gold that Fernand thought he had successfully stolen, he illustrates symbolically his disappointment with Fernand for selling out their friendship (the chess piece) for empty material wealth (the chests).

Comment: Great analysis of what's going on.  A lot more than just one upmanship